# How should simple database should look like with two tables?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am creating recipe app and all recipes I'm getting from database. I am using phpMyAdmin.

I had few classes about databases before so I know how to use it for simple tasks.

Now I have two tables `Recipes` and `Ingredients`. I have two simple questions:

1. Should I create separate `recipe id` or use the one that is assigned automatically?
   I will be searching for recipes in app and picking result I want from list.
2. How should I connect `Ingredients` table for every `Recipe` table.
   I think I should use some kind of ID ("reciep_id") same in both `Ingredient` and `Recipe` tables so I could connect them later when showing results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think that standard recipe id can be acceptable variant, because I can't imagine natural primary key for recipe.
2. Every your recipe includes some ingredients. And any ingredient can be used in more then one recipe. So you should use standard n-n relationship with link table.

Your tables can be like this ([link to sqlfiddle with this code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62c4b)):

```
CREATE TABLE Recipes (
 id int,
 name text,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE Ingredients(
 id int,
 name text,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE Recipes2Ingredients (
 rec_id int,
 ing_id int,
 amount int,
 -- and maybe some other needed fields
 FOREIGN KEY (rec_id)
   REFERENCES Recipes(id),
 FOREIGN KEY (ing_id)
   REFERENCES Ingredients(id)
);
```

Comment: I agree, but you should add some more attributes to `Recipes2Ingredients`, like `amount`. For example, for recipe #1 you need one onion (=ingredient) and for recipe #2 you need five onions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are right. I fix answer. I cook very rarely:) so I don't use recipes a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. I _do_ cook, that's probably why I thought of that. Besides that, your answer looks reasonable to me. One can think of a parent table for `Recipes` like `Group` (e.g. pork, noodles, veggie, ...) but that's beyond the OP's question.